# Does anyone know Facebook's "Page Insights API" metrics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been making a data connector that uses Facebook's page insights API. Everything was going well until the list of metric names for the API were taken off of the page I had been using for reference. Here is the url of the page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/insights`

I tried searching other Facebook pages in case they simply moved the list, but I was unable to find it anywhere. I also tried searching for metrics through other posts, but I was only able to find a handful.

I would appreciate it if someone could share any metric names you may know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Can you give an example what you are missing when using this API? The API seems to be fully documented.

Comment: a lot of stuff does not work right now on facebook, it may include the docs. not sure why you would tag javascript though, this is not related to any programming language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already had been reported as a bug and had been assigned. See https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2380036958945411/